# Using a stored date field to calculated a field that computes current number of days passed

Tags: mysql, calculated-columns

I am working with MySQL and phpMyAdmin. I have a 'date' field in my db and I need to create a field in the MySQL_db that will calculate and display the number of days that have past since the date in the 'date' field for each record/row.

I do not have the ability to generate the code on the fly with PHP.

Is there a way to create a field in MySQL that will give me the ability to display this calculation in the MySQL_db?

Comment: Is this not just an ALTER TABLE to add a calculated field?

Comment: Perhaps I should clarify.  What I am asking..is there a way to create a field in a MySQL TABLE, that will count the number of days from an existing DATE Field in the same table record/row?

Comment: So why the php tag?

Comment: re: why the Php Tag?  Mistake/removed

Answer (score 1):

You might like to read about the `CURDATE()` and `DATEDIFF()` functions (and other functions in MySQL that may be useful for you in the future) here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff

```
SELECT *, DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), mydatefield) AS days_since
FROM MyTable;
```

If you want this built in to the table, you can use a VIEW:

```
CREATE VIEW MyView AS
  SELECT *, DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), mydatefield) AS days_since
  FROM MyTable;
```

MySQL 5.7 supports [generated columns](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html) where you can add a virtual column based on an expression, but this doesn't work in this case because using a non-deterministic function like CURDATE() is not allowed in such expressions.

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD COLUMN days_since INT AS (DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), mydatefield));
ERROR 3102 (HY000): Expression of generated column 'days_since' contains a disallowed function.
```

Comment: I know that I could use DATEDIFF() to create this function IF I could change the Application (PhP) code.  I cannot.  My ONLY recourse is to have the 'day count' from the 'date' in question come right out of the MySQL table.  If that is not possible I have no other option available to me.

Comment: I guess I don't understand why the view doesn't meet your needs.